# CSS checkboxes with slanted labels

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I've been trying to achieve checkboxes with slanted text like the image below (where some level of overlapping is necessary):

[image: checkboxes with slanted text]

With using the transform styling and setting margins I have been able to get the text to be at the same vertical level, however I am having issues offsetting the  elements horizontally so that they appear beside each other.

(this is inside a dynamic table where the rows will be duplicated, which is why I used "span" instead of "label for" to avoid the complications with generating unique id's for all checkboxes)

```css
table tbody {
  display: block;
}

.angled_text {
  display: block;
  margin-top: -18px;
  transform:         rotate(-45deg);

  /* legacy */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform:    rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform:     rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform:      rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
  <table id="dynamic_table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <span class="angled_text">Monday</span>
          <span class="angled_text">Tuesday</span>
          <span class="angled_text">Wednesday</span>
          <span class="angled_text">Thursday</span>
          <span class="angled_text">Friday</span>
          
          <br>
  
          <input type="checkbox" name="monday" value="monday">
          <input type="checkbox" name="tuesday" value="tuesday">
          <input type="checkbox" name="wednesday" value="wednesday">
          <input type="checkbox" name="thursday" value="thursday">
          <input type="checkbox" name="friday" value="friday">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Should those spans be labels for the inputs in order for the HTML to be more accessible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change its `display: inline-block` and set the width of it.

The reason to set the `width` is that `transform` only changes the way the element is displayed, but its original space and position stays the same. By setting the `width` of it, you are actually changing the original vertical space that exists between the labels.

```css
table {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
table tbody {
  display: block;
}

.angled_text {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 18px;
  transform:         rotate(-45deg);

  /* legacy */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform:    rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform:     rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform:      rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
  <table id="dynamic_table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <span class="angled_text">Monday</span>
          <span class="angled_text">Tuesday</span>
          <span class="angled_text">Wednesday</span>
          <span class="angled_text">Thursday</span>
          <span class="angled_text">Friday</span>
          
          <br>
  
          <input type="checkbox" name="monday" value="monday">
          <input type="checkbox" name="tuesday" value="tuesday">
          <input type="checkbox" name="wednesday" value="wednesday">
          <input type="checkbox" name="thursday" value="thursday">
          <input type="checkbox" name="friday" value="friday">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Directly addressed the issue with a simple explanation, thank you! Is there a way to prevent the clipping of text at the top?

Comment: Thanks! For the top clipping, I updated the answer to include a simple `margin-top` on the table. But that should really depend on your layout. Just make sure your table has some top margin or padding. You may also be using another wrapper (like a `div`) for your content, that could have a padding. There's are many possibilities there :)

Comment: The problem with this technique is that is disassociates the width of the input with the  positioning of the text.  You can see even without any modifications (or text/font resizing) that Friday is not above the 5th checkbox, and it will get even more messy if you change the font-size, font-family, font-weight of either the spans, or the td (which will adjust the spacing between the inputs).  Also very anti-screen reader friendly (ADA/WCAG).

Comment: I agree with the comment @RobertMcKee. But isn't that a problem every time we use `transform`? I mean, it doesn't matter if it is in a `table`, `flex`, `block` or `inline` display, `relative` or `absolute` position... or maybe I am missing something.
It is valid to raise all that though, especially the screen reader point. But I guess that always depends on the project and its application.

Answer (score 3):

This is the way I would do it.  Wrap the input inside a label to make it clickable.  Positioning the child span using absolute positioning to take it outside the normal flow.  And add enough padding at the top of the div so that the labels don't get cut off.

```css
div {
  padding-top: 55px;
}
label.angled_text {
  margin-left: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

label.angled_text span {
  position: absolute;
  top: -14px;
  left: .5em;
  
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  /* legacy */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
  <div>
    <label class="angled_text">
      <input type="checkbox" name="monday" value="monday">
      <span>Monday</span>
    </label>
    <label class="angled_text">
      <input type="checkbox" name="tuesday" value="tuesday">
      <span>Tuesday</span>
    </label>
    <label class="angled_text">
      <input type="checkbox" name="wednesday" value="wednesday">
      <span>Wednesday</span>
    </label>
    <label class="angled_text">
      <input type="checkbox" name="thursday" value="thursday">
      <span>Thursday</span>
    </label>
    <label class="angled_text">
      <input type="checkbox" name="friday" value="friday">
      <span>Friday</span>
    </label>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I very much like how this one keeps the checkbox and label/caption for each checkbox together as a unit (as when all the labels and checkboxes are separate they can start to misalign as more checkboxes and labels are added in)

Answer (score 0):

`inline-block` won't cut it, since the rotation destroys the horizontal layout. Use `flex` layout instead. Note the css requires some manual tweaking for width and so on. Maybe there's a more elegant way, but this does the job:

```
    <html lang="en">
    <body >
      <div class="flex labels">
        <span class="angled_text">Monday</span>
        <span class="angled_text">Tuesday</span>
        <span class="angled_text">Wednesday</span>
        <span class="angled_text">Thursday</span>
        <span class="angled_text">Friday</span>
      </div>

      <div class="flex">
        <input type="checkbox" name="monday" value="monday">
        <input type="checkbox" name="tuesday" value="tuesday">
        <input type="checkbox" name="wednesday" value="wednesday">
        <input type="checkbox" name="thursday" value="thursday">
        <input type="checkbox" name="friday" value="friday">
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

```
    .flex {
      display: flex;
    }

    .labels {
      margin-top: 30px;
    }

    input {
      width: 30px;
    }

    .angled_text {
      display: block;
      width: 35px;
      position: relative;
      top: -10px;
      left: 5px;
      transform:         rotate(-45deg);

      /* legacy */
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
      -moz-transform:    rotate(-45deg);
      -ms-transform:     rotate(-45deg);
      -o-transform:      rotate(-45deg);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Table`

```css
table tbody {
  display: block;
}

.angled_text {
  display: block;
  margin-top: -18px;
  transform:         rotate(-45deg);

  /* legacy */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform:    rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform:     rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform:      rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
  <table id="dynamic_table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <span class="angled_text">Monday</span>
          </td>
          <td>
          <span class="angled_text">Tuesday</span>
          </td>
          <td>
          <span class="angled_text">Wednesday</span>
          </td>
          <td>
          <span class="angled_text">Thursday</span>
          </td>
          <td>
          <span class="angled_text">Friday</span>
          </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <br>
          <td><br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="monday" value="monday">
          </td>
          <td><br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="tuesday" value="tuesday">
          </td>
          <td><br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="wednesday" value="wednesday">
          </td>
          <td><br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="thursday" value="thursday">
          </td>
          <td><br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="friday" value="friday">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

hope this help you.